# Using gcloud to ssh into specific linux username

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I am brand new to GCP and I'm running a single VM instance for which I'm using gcloud to connect to.

I notice that when I connect from my laptop I ssh into the linux user `mylaptop` and when I connect from my desktop I ssh into the linux user `mydesktop`.

I was hoping there was a way to ssh into `mylaptop` from my desktop machine.

I have tried coping the `.ssh` directory from my laptop to my desktop but this gave an error.

I have also experimented with `su mylaptop` but I am running into issues with different python environments and missing packages when I use this approach.

Is there an easy gcloud solution for this?

Comment: On your desktop machine ... what is your local userid and what exact command are you running to ssh to your GCP Compute Engine instance?

Comment: Could you also please write the error that you are getting? This would be helpful for us in order to know what is happening.

Comment: @Kolban, my apologies but what do you mean by local userid? The way I log into the Google VM is through the Google Cloud Console. Under `Compute Engine -> VM Instances` I select `view gcloud command` from the drop down menu under `connect` on the VM instance. The command is `gcloud beta compute --project 'my-project' ssh --zone 'us-east1-d' 'tensorflow-1-vm'`

Comment: @eespinola, I only received an error when I copied the `.ssh` folder from my laptop to my desktop and tried to ssh into the VM. I thought perhaps that would allow me to log into the `mylaptop` user on the VM. The error I get when I try that is `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the gcloud compute ssh command to start ssh, it supports setting the user name directly:

```
gcloud compute ssh [USER@]INSTANCE
```

So you should be able login as the mylaptop user like this:

```
gcloud compute ssh mylaptop@INSTANCE
```

Comment: If (like me) you want to know your login : `gcloud compute os-login describe-profile --format json|jq -r '.posixAccounts[].username'`